# tensorflow import error :cannot import name 'module_wrapper' from 'tensorflow.python.util'

Tags: python, tensorflow

Code: import tensorflow

Gives the following error

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-d6579f534729>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1019, in _handle_fromlist
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import node_def_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_node__def__pb2
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\node_def_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\resource_handle_pb2.py", line 92, in <module>
    __module__ = 'tensorflow.core.framework.resource_handle_pb2'
TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2033, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1095, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 313, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 347, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v1 import app
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v1\app\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util import module_wrapper as _module_wrapper
ImportError: cannot import name 'module_wrapper' from 'tensorflow.python.util' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\__init__.py)
```

I have installed tensorflow using the following command:

> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0

Same issue occurs while importing keras too. Also note that I am new to tensorflow and keras

Answer (score 0):

Try installing tensorflow with conda.

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
```

If you still have problems you can delete the environment and install with conda the first time.

Comment: It worked by running anaconda as administrator. Now am not getting any error for tensorflow but the error is still the same while importing keras